# PPA build fails only in one distribution and on one architecture

Tags: ppa, packaging

I'm trying to publish a package to my PPA, which builds find on my system, both native and using pbuilder (both trusty and precise). But when I upload it to PPA, the trusty AMD64 build fails for some reason, tough the i386 build succeeds as well as both AMD64 and i386 on precise.

I've looked at the build log from PPA, and compared it to the precise AMD64 build:

[trusty AMD64 build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/199435804/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-amd64.openblas_0.2.13-1ubuntu5~trusty1_BUILDING.txt.gz)

[prcise AMD64 build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/199435559/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.openblas_0.2.13-1ubuntu5_BUILDING.txt.gz)

The first difference I see is that after completing `dh_clean`, the trusty build says `debian/rules build-arch` while the precise build says `debian/rules build`. After that the trusty build doesn't run `make` and as a result fails in `dh_install`, while the precise build has everything working.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: In the trusty version, it looks like it's not even being compiled. Also, the `debian/rules` file is based on a old standard, which doesn't even have `build-arch` and `build-indep`. I'll see if I can bring it up to date and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that it's now expected that the `debian/rules` file either uses the newer `dh_*` target names (which this doesn't) or that there are `build-arch` and `build-indep` target names.

If you look in Ubuntu's `debian/rules`, you'll see that [for Trusty](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/openblas/trusty/view/head:/debian/rules), they've make a `build-arch` target that calls `build-stamp`, and made `build` depend on `build-arch`. This is a quick fix to the problem.

Alternatively, if you want to switch to the newer `dh_*` targets, you can look at Debian's [debian folder](https://sources.debian.net/src/openblas/0.2.12-1/debian/), and download the `debian.tar.xz` file from [here](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/openblas). This should work on Precise and Trusty.

Comment: The `build-arch: build-stamp` change worked fine and now my packages build, thanks! I looked at the debian files for openblas on sid, as you recommended, but they look identical to what I was using - specifically, it is what I was using ;-) If you can point me to an example using the newer `dh_*` targets, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I just now looked at the link to debian sources, and there the `rules` file is indeed very different - I'll see what I can make of that. Thanks again!